# Compiler compliance level error in Android console

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

```
[2012-07-03 13:21:02 - BroadCastRcvrReadPhoneState] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.4' instead.
Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

I don't get it. Any idea how to solve this problem..

Answer (score 2):

Right click your Project, Click **AndroidTools->** and inside the sub menus, click on **Fix Project properties**

If this doesn't work, Right click the project, click on `Properties->java compiler->` click on `Enable project specific Settings` and then , Select **Compiler Compliance Level** . And now select the highest compiler level in the drop down list.

Answer (score 2):

in Eclise go to:

```
Window->Prefrences->Java->Compiler->Compiler Compliance Level
```

and change the Compile compliance level to 1.6